# Pass a dictionary from one function to another function and print it

Tags: c#, function, dictionary, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

My goal is to pass `myDictionary` from `function1` to `function2` and print it from `function2`. I am a newbie so it is quite possible my syntax or format is incorrect.

```
// This is my main program
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        function1();
    }
}

// Create myDictionary in this function and then pass it to function2
static public void function1()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    myDictionary.Add("FirstName", "John");
    myDictionary.Add("LastName", "Walter");

    // passing myDictionary to another function
    function2(myDictionary);
}

// Passing myDictionary to this function
static public function2(myDictionary<string, string>)
{
    // print myDictionary from here 
}
```

Comment: So what's is the exact problem you're asking about? It does not compile? Or you're trying to find appropriate method for printing?

Answer (score 1):

Declare you 2nd function like this:

```
//passing myDictionary to this function
static public void function2(Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary)
{
    foreach (var v in myDictionary)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", v.Key, v.Value));
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> function2(Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary)
{
    // print myDictionary from here 
}
```

For each parameter, you need to specify the type, followed by the name of the parameter.

Comment: ...and specify a return type.

Answer (score 0):

A method or function may have a list of parameters. That's the part between the parentheses after the method's name:

```
void FunctionName( /* parameters here */ )
{
}
```

A parameter always looks like this:

```
Type name
```

Where `Type` is the type of the value, and `name` is any legal identifier you want. If you want multiple parameters, separate them with comma's:

```
void MethodName(Type1 name1, Type2 name2)
{
}
```

Also note the `void` before the method name. This indicates that the method is expected to *return no value*. if you want your function to return a value, simply replace `void` by the *type* of value you want it to return.

---

In your case, `Dictionary<string, string>` is the type, and the name could be, for example, `someDictionary`. Note that it doesn't have to be `myDictionary`, but it can be.

```
static public void PrintDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> someDictionary)
{
    // print someDictionary from here 
}
```

And then you call it like you did:

```
PrintDictionary(myDictionary);
```

The rest of your code is correct. You'll only have to find out how to print your dictionary. For example:

```
static public void PrintDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> someDictionary)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in someDictionary)
    {
        Console.Write(pair.Key);
        Console.Write(" => ");
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Value);
    }
}
```

---

Note that I changed the name `function2` to `PrintDictionary` in my examples. A method or function name should be a meaningful name, and the C# convention is to start it with an upper-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

You need not add a seperate variable you can call the function2 like below.

```
static public void function1()
{

    // passing myDictionary to another function
    function2(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "FirstName", "John" }, { "LastName", "Walter" } });
}
```